# "commenting out" in Jira markup

Tags: jira, markup

This seems like such a simple question, but I've given it the obligatory 30 minutes of Googling, and I'm coming up with nothing.

We have pretty strict formatting requirements for our Jira tickets, but those tickets come into Jira from a variety of automated sources which we can't control.  I'm putting together a service that inspects Jira tickets using the API, and applies the correct formatting if necessary.  This would save us a lot of annoying labour.

It would be *really* useful if I could put invisible comments in the body of comment text, for both auditing purposes and manipulating the text.  I can't find any official/legitimate way of doing this.  I don't really think there'd be much call for it, aside from my quite specialist needs.

So does anyone have any ideas for Jira text markup tricks that would give readable comments in raw text form, but which wouldn't visibly render once the markup is applied?  I'll take a moderately future-proof hacky kludge.  Simply changing the text colour is not an option.

Comment: Sorry, didn't really understand, what are you trying to achieve? editing the body? editing comments? adding comments? mind giving an example?

Comment: Hmm. The Source Code editor plugin lets you see the underlying XHTML where you could add HTML comments.

Comment: I would take this to the Atlassian Forums. As far as I can remember, you could create a custom field. I don't think it would be wise to append comments to the issue body.

Comment: I've found a solution now.  As for an example, let's say I get a ticket with a badly formatted description field.  My service should pull out relevant content and prepend the description with the correctly formatted information.  Being able to leave machine-readable comments in there makes it a lot easier.

Comment: As long as you found a solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I've ended up getting around this is to use anchors:

```
{anchor: this text will not appear in the marked-up text in Jira}
```

It's not ideal, but it does the job, and shouldn't be removed in future versions of Jira.

Comment: Thanks!  I use this as `{anchor: vim:set filetype=confluencewiki nonu linebreak showbreak=...\  wrap nolist: }` so that I can edit JIRA comments in Vim, using [confluencewiki](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1994) syntax with the [It's All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/its-all-text/) Firefox plugin.

Answer (score 0):

- I would create a new Role.  Set the comment's visibility to that
  specific role.
- To set it using REST take a look [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Add+Comment#JIRARESTAPIExample-AddComment-Examplealsosettingthesecuritylevel).
- For users who must see this comment, they should be assigned the specific role
  which is documented [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Managing+Project+Role+Membership).
- This should guarantee that your updates will not be deleted by JIRA upgrade.

Comment: This answers a different question, viz., "How can I hide specific JIRA comments?"  The original question is completely different: "How can I 'comment out' a _part_ of a JIRA description of comment, so that it only shows up in the 'source' form of the description or comment, and not in the final marked up form?"